# c++ Unable to use functions on Nodes in a vector<Node*>

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to make a c++ program that emulates parts of a linux filesystem.

I have a vector<Node*>. In order to add to it I have to first create a Node* that I then .push_back() to the vector, right?
Is it possible to .push_back() without having to first create another Node* to push_back()?

Another problem is that I cannot invoke any methods on the nodes inside of the vector<Node*>. In order to do anything with them like, say, use a GetName() method on it, I have to first create a Node* with the index of the vector that has the data I want to use. I am fairly certain that this way of going about it is what's causing me so much grief.

What's killing me right now is that when I test all the associated methods in a separate main.cpp file, they all cooperate and do what I want. When I run them through a TEST_CASE however, they misbehave and cause a crash. I can't think of anything that could be causing these problems mostly because they behave in a main method.

For Reference, here's all my code:
node.hpp:

```
#ifndef NODE_HPP
#define NODE_HPP
using namespace std;
#include <string>
#include <vector>
class Node {
    private:
        char type;
        string name;
        vector<Node*> children;
        Node* parent;
        void RemoveHelper(Node* subtree);
    public:
        Node(string name, char type);
        Node();
        ~Node();
        void AddChild(Node* child);
        void AddChild(string name, char type);
        bool RemoveChild(string name);
        void SetParent(Node* parent);
        void SetType(char type);
        Node* GetChild(string name);
        vector<Node*> GetChildren();
        Node* GetParent();
        char GetType();
        string GetName();
};

#endif
```

node.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

#include "node.hpp"

void Node::RemoveHelper(Node* subtree){
    for (int j = 0; j < subtree->GetChildren().size(); j++){
        //cout << j << " ";
        Node* n = subtree->GetChildren()[j];
        if (!n->GetChildren().empty()){
            for (int i = 0; i < n->GetChildren().size(); i++){
                //cout << i << endl;
                RemoveHelper(subtree->GetChildren()[i]);
                subtree->RemoveChild(n->GetName());
            }
        }
    }
}

Node::Node(){
    name = "";
    type = ' ';
    parent = nullptr;
}

Node::Node(string name, char type){
    this->name = name;
    this->type = type;
    parent = nullptr;
}

Node::~Node(){
    children.clear();
}

void Node::AddChild(string name, char type){
    Node* n = new Node(name, type);
    AddChild(n);
    delete n;
}

void Node::AddChild(Node* child){
    children.push_back(child);
}

bool Node::RemoveChild(string name){
    Node* n = GetChild(name);
    for (int i = 0; i < children.size(); i++){
        if (n == children[i]){
            RemoveHelper(children[i]);
            children.erase(children.begin()+i);
            //delete n;
            return true;
        }
    }   
    return false;
}

void Node::SetParent(Node * parent){
    this->parent = parent;
}

void Node::SetType(char type){
    this->type = type;
}

Node* Node::GetChild(string name){
    for (int i = 0; i < children.size(); i++){
        Node* n = children[i];
        if (n->GetName() == name){
            //delete n;
            return children[i];
        }
        //delete n;
    }
    return nullptr;
}

vector<Node*> Node::GetChildren(){
    return children;
}

Node* Node::GetParent(){
    return parent;
}

char Node::GetType(){
    return type;
}

string Node::GetName(){
    return name;
}
```

filesystem.hpp:

```
#ifndef FILESYSTEM_HPP
#define FILESYSTEM_HPP
using namespace std;
#include <string>
#include "node.hpp"

class FileSystem {
    private:
        Node* root;
        Node* currentDirectory;
        void AddNode(Node* newNode);
        Node* FindNode(string name);
    public:
        FileSystem();
        ~FileSystem();
        string mkdir(string name);
        string touch(string name);
        string pwd();
        string ls();
        string rm(string name);
        string mv(string from, string to);
        string cd(string dirname);
};

#endif
```

filesystem.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

#include "filesystem.hpp"
#include "node.hpp"

void FileSystem::AddNode(Node* newNode){
    currentDirectory->AddChild(newNode);
    currentDirectory->GetChild(newNode->GetName())->SetParent(currentDirectory);
}

Node* FileSystem::FindNode(string name){
    return currentDirectory->GetChild(name);
}

FileSystem::FileSystem(){
    root = new Node("root", 'd');
    currentDirectory = root;
}

FileSystem::~FileSystem(){
    for (int i = root->GetChildren().size(); i > i; i--){
        Node* n = root->GetChildren()[i];
        root->RemoveChild(n->GetName());
        //delete n;
    }
    delete root;
    
    for (int i = currentDirectory->GetChildren().size(); i > 0; i--){
        Node* n = currentDirectory->GetChildren()[i];
        currentDirectory->RemoveChild(n->GetName());
        delete n;
    }
    delete currentDirectory;
}

string FileSystem::mkdir(string name){
    if (currentDirectory->GetChild(name) == nullptr){
        Node* n = new Node(name, 'd');
        AddNode(n);
        
        return "directory " + name + " created successfully";
    }
    return "Error: " + name + " exists";
}

string FileSystem::touch(string name){
    if (currentDirectory->GetChild(name) == nullptr){
        currentDirectory->AddChild(name, 'f');
        return "file " + name + " created successfully";
    }
    return "Error: " + name + " exists";
}

// I know that this only works for up to 3 directories. That's fine for this project.
string FileSystem::pwd(){
    string ret = "/" + root->GetName();
    if (root != currentDirectory){
        if (currentDirectory->GetParent() != root){
            ret += "/" + currentDirectory->GetParent()->GetName();
        }
        ret += "/" + currentDirectory->GetName();
    }
    return ret;
}

string FileSystem::ls(){
    string ret = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < currentDirectory->GetChildren().size(); i++){
        Node* n = currentDirectory->GetChildren()[i];
        ret += n->GetType();
        ret += " " + n->GetName() + "\n";
        //delete n;
    }
    return ret;
}

string FileSystem::rm(string name){
    if (currentDirectory->RemoveChild(name)){
        return name + " removed successfully";
    }
    return "No such file or directory";
}

string FileSystem::mv(string from, string to){
    currentDirectory->AddChild(to, currentDirectory->GetChild(from)->GetType());
    currentDirectory->RemoveChild(from);
    return "file/dir renamed successfully";
}

string FileSystem::cd(string dirname){
    cout << currentDirectory->GetChild("dir");
    if ((dirname == ".." && currentDirectory == root) || dirname == currentDirectory->GetName()){
        return "can't change to directory " + dirname;
    }
    else if (dirname == ".."){
        currentDirectory = root;
    }
    else if (currentDirectory->GetChild(dirname) == nullptr){
        return "can't change to directory " + dirname;
    }
    else{
        currentDirectory = currentDirectory->GetChild(dirname);
    }
    return pwd();
}
```

One of the test files:

```
#include "catch/catch.hpp"
#include "../filesystem.hpp"

TEST_CASE("Test creating a file system")
{
    FileSystem fs;
    CHECK ("/root" == fs.pwd());
    CHECK ("" == fs.ls());
}

TEST_CASE ("Test touch and mkdir")
{
    FileSystem fs;
    CHECK ("file file1 created successfully" == fs.touch("file1"));
    CHECK ("Error: file1 exists" == fs.touch("file1"));
    CHECK ("file file2 created successfully" == fs.touch("file2"));
    CHECK ("directory dir1 created successfully" == fs.mkdir("dir1"));
    CHECK ("Error: dir1 exists" == fs.mkdir("dir1"));
    CHECK ("Error: dir1 exists" == fs.touch("dir1"));
    CHECK ("f file1\nf file2\nd dir1\n" == fs.ls());
    CHECK ("/root" == fs.pwd());
}
```

If there is anything else anyone catches that could help avoid other issues I haven't caught yet, that would also be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There are violations of the [rule of 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) in each of your classes.

Comment: I had not look through all your code, but in method `AddChild` you create a new node through a pointer `n`, but after you have pushed it, you delete it. The data pointed by this value is therefore deleted, hence, the data in your vector is corrupted (your `push_back` copies the pointer, not the data). You should simply do: `vector.push_back(new Node(args));` and that's all.

Comment: smart pointers might help to avoid manual memory management.

Comment: Could you explain how you "cannot invoke any methods on the nodes inside of the vector<Node*>". It looks like you're doing that all over the place.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is not that you can't invoke methods on nodes inside of  vector of children. Your problem is that you're trying to invoke Node methods on random memory, because you have deleted the nodes beforehand and the memory now contains whatever.

You have to understand the difference between an object and a pointer to the object. Pointer is not an object, it's just its address. You can store the address of the object in multiple places and all those places would **point** to the very same object.

In your particular case you're storing a bunch od **addresses** of `Node` objects in the vector called `children`. So when you add a child to your `Node`, you create a new object (this is what `new` does), but then you just store the address of that object. When you store an address to the object, the object itself is not touched. This is similar to a situation when you give your mail address to someone. They may do whatever with that address. If that person gives your address to someone else you don't feel it nor does your clone spawn somewhere.

So when you stored the address of that new child in `children` vector, this newly created child is not copied anywhere, it stays exactly where you created it at the address you were given back as a result of `new` operator and which you subsequently stored in `children`.

So you must not delete freshly created child just after you add it to your `Node`. You must wait with deletion until you remove that particular child from the `Node`.

---

Back to your case:

The problem is in this code:

```
void Node::AddChild(string name, char type){
    Node* n = new Node(name, type);
    AddChild(n);
    delete n;  // <-- HERE'S THE ISSUE
}
```

What the above code does is:

1. It creates a new `Node`
2. It stores **pointer** to that `Node` in variable `n`
3. It now executes `AddChild` which stores the **pointer** into `children` vector
4. It deletes the `Node` it created in step 1. From that very moment the stored **pointer** doesn't point to any `Node`, it points to garbage. It's now a so called *dangling pointer*.

To fix the immediate issue you should stop deleting the `Node` just after insertion. You should delete the node after it's removed from children, i.e. in `Node::RemoveChild` method:

```
bool Node::RemoveChild(string name){
    Node* n = GetChild(name);
    for (int i = 0; i < children.size(); i++){
        if (n == children[i]){
            RemoveHelper(children[i]);
            children.erase(children.begin()+i);
            delete n;  // <-- YOU WANT THIS DELETE, HERE YOU DELETE THE NODE
            return true;
        }
    }   
    return false;
}
```

---

But, the above is just an immediate fix. The real proper option is to actually use smart pointers. Usually `std::unique_ptr` is the right one (and at first glance it indeed seems correct in your case). Smart pointers remove the need of explicit deletion

The first step would be to change the children vector definition:

```
vector<std::unique_ptr<Node>> children;
```

The next step would be to modify your `Node::AddChild` method:

```
void Node::AddChild(string name, char type){
    AddChild(std::make_unique<Node>(name, type));
}
```

Then in all other places when you assingn to some `Node*` you do

```
Node* n = `THE_THING_GIVING_YOU_NODE`.get();
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing where the delete belonged. I implemented the quick fix, but now I am getting very inconsistent behavior from the methods in filesystem.cpp. Running the provided tests results in a SIGABRT after ls() passes. Another test gets through ls() without trouble. Does anything stick out that may cause this sort of unreliable behavior?